# Search forward using word at point

Tags: isearch

I would like to search the current buffer for particular words.
To make a function that takes the word at point and searches for that word in the current buffer.  Hopefully with match word highlighting as when using `isearch-forward`.

Have started with the following, but I get the `isearch-forward` in the minibuffer as normal instead.  What can I do?

```
(defun gala-search-forward ()
  "TODO"
  (interactive)

  (let* ( (bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word))
          (word   (downcase
                   (buffer-substring (car bounds) (cdr bounds)))))

    (isearch-forward word)))
```

Comment: isearch-forward's first parameter is the prefix argument `(C-u)`, *not* a string to search for.  I think you want something like `search-forward` instead, but it's not clear from your question precisely what you mean by "does a search".

Comment: Not germane to this question but I have seen variants on this code several times now and wonder why you don't just  `(let ((word (downcase (thing-at-point 'word t)))))` and lose the `bounds`.

Comment: Thusly I can do even better with `(interactive (list (downcase (thing-at-point 'word t))))`.  Right?

Comment: Sure: if you make `word` the argument of `gala-search-forward`: `(defun gala-search-forward (word)...)`

Comment: @PhilHudson: Please provide your comment as an answer (it's the answer). Or OP: consider deleting the question, if you don't think it and the answer will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isearch-forward`, but instead of typing letters to search for, just hit `C-w` to "yank next word or character in buffer onto the end of the search string, and search for it."  (See the doc string for isearch-forward.)

Or maybe I'm misunderstanding your question?

Comment: You understood well.